# error in typing (datetime.d.ts) file which doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2022, typing

I installed the typings for luxon with `npm install --save-dev @types/luxon`. Afterall I realized I don't need it and so I removed it manually:

- removed folder node_modules/@types/**luxon**
- removed entries in package.json
- removed entries referencing luxon in package-lock.json

After building in Visual Studio 2022 I always get the error:

> Build:Namespace 'Intl' has no exported member 'DateTimeFormatPart' and under the column Project this path (which doesn't exist) - the real path of the message was replaced by ...:
> C:\dev\...\node_modules@types\luxon\src\datetime.d.ts 1238

I also tried to use `npm prune`, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixable by removing the `node_modules` directory (i.e. `rm -r node_modules`, or the window equivalent), followed by a clean install: `npm install`.

To prevent the problem in the future, a better way to uninstall packages is with `npm uninstall`, e.g. `npm uninstall @types/luxon`. Alternatively, you can remove the package from the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` in your `package.json` and run `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my folder structure.
My FrontendCode is under c:\dev\solutionPath\ProjectPath and in this folder there is the node_modules folder. But one time accidentally I did npm install one folder above so under c:\dev\solutionPath there was also a node_models folder.